# Centering table items when they are responsive

Tags: html, css, html-email

I need some assistance with my code for an HTML email. I am trying to make the "resort boxes" center once the screen is smaller. Meaning when it is view on a phone. I have tried so many things, but still cant figure it out. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"><!--<![endif]-->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

    <title>
    </title>
    <style type="text/css">

           @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
           body,table,td,p,a,li,blockquote {
           -webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;
           font-size:90%;
           }
           table {width: 100% !important;}
           .responsive-image img {
           height: auto !important;
           max-width: 100% !important;
           width: 100% !important;
           }

           }   


    table {border-collapse: collapse;}

           /* Basics */
    body {
       margin: 0 !important;
       padding: 0;
       background-color: #e4e4e4;
    }
    table {
       border-spacing: 0;
       font-family: sans-serif;
       color: #333333;
    }
    td {
       padding: 0;

    }
    img {
       border: 0;
       max-width: 100%; 
       display:block; 
       height: auto;
    }
    div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] { 
       margin:0 !important;
    }
    .wrapper {
       width: 100%;
       table-layout: fixed;
       -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
       -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }
    .webkit {
       max-width: 600px;
       margin: 0 auto;
    }

    a {
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    .more a {

       color: white;
       text-decoration: underline;
       line-height: 2em;
       font-family:  sans-serif;

               }
       /*box text content*/
        .resort-name{color: #000000; font-size:20px;  line-height: 1em; font-family: sans-serif;text-align: center}
        .city {color: #615657; font-size:12px;text-align: center}
        .rate {color: #758b1d; font-size:20px; text-align: center}
        .rate-s {color:#969696; text-align: center}

    div.cont table 
    {
       margin: 0 auto; 

    }

    </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #e4e4e4">
    <center class="wrapper">
        <div class="webkit" style="background-color:#010044">
            <!-- VRI Logo-->

            <table align="center" bgcolor="#E4E4E4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600px">
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="http://www.8664myvacation.com"><img alt="vri-logo" src=
                    "https://mlsvc01-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/483a2626be/f0966faf-85e8-4138-85cc-c5bacc31694e.png?ver=1492203807000" style="padding: 40px 0 15px 5px"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- Insert Header Here -->

            <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600px">
                <tr align="justify">
                    <td><img alt="HEADER_IMG" class="header" src="https://mlsvc01-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/483a2626be/93869145-c989-4ae6-a9ce-6b48201903ab.jpg?ver=1493324994000">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- End Promo Code Section -->
            <!-- Promo Code Section -->


            <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#010044" width="600">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h1 align="center" style="color: white; font-family:'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;">Promo Code: CALI</h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- End Promo Code Section -->
            <!-- Resort Section-->


            <div class="container">
                <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="95%">
                    <tbody>
                        <!-- Resort 1-->


                        <tr style="background-color: white; max-width: 270px; display: inline-block; margin: 7.5px;">
                            <td>
                                <a href="http://www.8664myvacation.com/rentResortInfoSheets.php?prop=tsr&promo=CALI" target="_blank"><img alt="Tahoe Seasons Resort" src=
                                "https://mlsvc01-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/483a2626be/daabeb63-91a4-4c04-9811-b5b42d74ca58.png?ver=1483132264000" style="width: 270;" title="Tahoe Seasons Resort"></a>

                                <div style="padding:10px; text-align: center; valign: top; line-height: 1.25em;">
                                    <!-- Resort name & city info --><span class="resort-name"><strong>Tahoe Seasons Resort</strong></span><br>
                                    <span class="city">S. Lake Tahoe, CA</span> <!-- End resort name & city info -->
                                     <!-- Horizontal rule -->

                                    <hr style="width: 20%; align: center; margin-bottom: 10px">
                                    <!-- End horizontal rule -->
                                    <!-- Resort strikethrough rate --><span style="color: #000000; font-size:16px"><b>From</b> <s style="color:#969696">$122/night</s><br>
                                    <br></span> <!-- End resort special rate -->
                                     <!-- Resort special rate -->
                                    <span style="color: #758b1d; font-size:20px"><b>$98/night</b></span> <!-- End resort special rate -->
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- End Resort 1 -->
                        <!-- Resort 2-->


                        <tr style="background-color: white; max-width: 270px; display: inline-block; margin: 7.5px;">
                            <td>
                                <a href="http://www.8664myvacation.com/rentResortInfoSheets.php?prop=tsr&promo=CALI" target="_blank"><img alt="Tahoe Seasons Resort" src=
                                "https://mlsvc01-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/483a2626be/daabeb63-91a4-4c04-9811-b5b42d74ca58.png?ver=1483132264000" style="width: 270;" title="Tahoe Seasons Resort"></a>

                                <div style="padding:10px; text-align: center; valign: top; line-height: 1.25em;">
                                    <!-- Resort name & city info --><span class="resort-name"><strong>Tahoe Seasons Resort</strong></span><br>
                                    <span class="city">S. Lake Tahoe, CA</span> <!-- End resort name & city info -->
                                     <!-- Horizontal rule -->

                                    <hr style="width: 20%; align: center; margin-bottom: 10px">
                                    <!-- End horizontal rule -->
                                    <!-- Resort strikethrough rate --><span style="color: #000000; font-size:16px"><b>From</b> <s style="color:#969696">$122/night</s><br>
                                    <br></span> <!-- End resort special rate -->
                                     <!-- Resort special rate -->
                                    <span style="color: #758b1d; font-size:20px"><b>$98/night</b></span> <!-- End resort special rate -->
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- End Resort 2 -->
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <!-- ADS SECTION-->


                <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#010044" width="600">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="width: 275px; padding: 10px"><a href="http://www.8664myvacation.com/rentHome.php" target="_blank"><img alt="VRI_Ad" height="" src=
                        "https://mlsvc01-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/483a2626be/24f8c582-4b04-4af6-9da6-2b0a182b54bf.png?ver=1486058446000" width="560"></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="width: 275px; padding: 10px;"><a href="https://www.avis.com/car-rental/profile/go.ac?D415600" target="_blank"><img alt="Avis_Ad.jpg"
                        height="" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/401702/Avis_Ad.jpg" width="560"></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!-- START FOOTER=-->


                <footer>
                    <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#63656b;display:table;" width="600">
                        <tr>
                            <td height="15" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding:20;">
                                <blockquote>
                                    <p style="color:#ffffff; font-size:10px; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; text-align:left;">Terms and Conditions:<br>
                                    PROMO CODE: CALI. Valid for new reservations booked between 5/3/2017 - 5/12/2017 for travel from 5/3/2017 - 8/31/2017. Please enter promo code CALI when making your
                                    online booking to receive best available rate. Offer is based on availability and may not be available on all room types, Rates may be higher during holiday/event periods
                                    and weekends. Cannot be combined with other offers and promotions and is subject to change without notice.</p>
                                </blockquote>
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr bgcolor="#63656B">
                            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="padding:20px 0px;color:#000000;">
                                <table align="center" bgcolor="#63656B" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#63656B;margin-bottom:10px;" width="600px">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="color:#ffffff;font-weight:normal;vertical-align:top;font-size:12px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;line-;text-align:center;"
                                        valign="top">
                                            <div style="line-height: 2em; display: inline;">
                                                <center>
                                                    <a class="imgCaptionAnchor" href=
                                                    "http://r20.rs6.net/tn.jsp?f=001VYiWL5i82Ann9qRcISgE6Vp48wcxwnCtzt3iPLVLHE1Nb2KStjtSlaZpsSubBK-vW90CHuojdBnC8cqIWSmfwEfEosTJw_00x6b3LPt2nIOrLNT6cYshOKU511zD5sDgXwusveQqP6VGDBwGiG1Mv-fBkTEz9VTNaBX1_tVKgEQ7cQjl_S28CQ==&c=&ch="
                                                    shape="rect" target="_blank"><img alt="Vacation Resorts International" border="0" height="24" hspace="0" src=
                                                    "http://www.8664myvacation.com/eguest/images/vri-logo-footer.gif" vspace="0" width="40"></a><br>
                                                    <a href="#" shape="rect" style="color:rgb(255, 255, 255);font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none;">25510 Commercentre Dr., Suite 100<br>
                                                    Lake Forest, CA 92630<br>
                                                    866-469-8222</a><br>
                                                    &#169;2017 Vacation Resorts International
                                                </center>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- End 4 Columns -->


                    <div class="" style="height: 40px; margin:0 auto; background-color: #e4e4e4; width: 100%">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <!-- spacer -->
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FWIW, you're using a lot of depreciated markup, i.e. `<center>` tag, `align`, `bgcolor` attributes etc. Seems to me they're not necessary. What's the requirement for using a table here? Tables shouldn't be used for page layout.

Comment: @hungerstar I'm assuming it's an html email.

Comment: That's true, would explain a lot.

Comment: Hi everyone this an html email. Sorry I am self-taught, so I am sure my coding is old and sloppy lol. Thanks for the help. The text-align: center worked perfect! Thanks both @hungerstar and big thanks Michael Coker

Comment: At first I thought this was a web page and was like **what!?!?** Lolz, but if it's an HTML email then you're sometimes stuck having to use older conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Your `tr`'s are `display: inline-block;` and already have a confined width that puts them in the box, so `text-align: center` on the parent will center those elements.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"><!--<![endif]-->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

    <title>
    </title>
    <style type="text/css">

           @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
           body,table,td,p,a,li,blockquote {
           -webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;
           font-size:90%;
           }
           table {width: 100% !important;}
           .responsive-image img {
           height: auto !important;
           max-width: 100% !important;
           width: 100% !important;
           }

           }   


    table {border-collapse: collapse;}

           /* Basics */
    body {
       margin: 0 !important;
       padding: 0;
       background-color: #e4e4e4;
    }
    table {
       border-spacing: 0;
       font-family: sans-serif;
       color: #333333;
    }
    td {
       padding: 0;

    }
    img {
       border: 0;
       max-width: 100%; 
       display:block; 
       height: auto;
    }
    div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] { 
       margin:0 !important;
    }
    .wrapper {
       width: 100%;
       table-layout: fixed;
       -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
       -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    }
    .webkit {
       max-width: 600px;
       margin: 0 auto;
    }

    a {
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    .more a {

       color: white;
       text-decoration: underline;
       line-height: 2em;
       font-family:  sans-serif;

               }
       /*box text content*/
        .resort-name{color: #000000; font-size:20px;  line-height: 1em; font-family: sans-serif;text-align: center}
        .city {color: #615657; font-size:12px;text-align: center}
        .rate {color: #758b1d; font-size:20px; text-align: center}
        .rate-s {color:#969696; text-align: center}

    div.cont table 
    {
       margin: 0 auto; 

    }

    </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #e4e4e4">
    <center class="wrapper">
        <div class="webkit" style="background-color:#010044">
            <!-- VRI Logo-->

            <table align="center" bgcolor="#E4E4E4" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600px">
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="http://www.8664myvacation.com"><img alt="vri-logo" src=
                    "https://mlsvc01-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/483a2626be/f0966faf-85e8-4138-85cc-c5bacc31694e.png?ver=1492203807000" style="padding: 40px 0 15px 5px"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- Insert Header Here -->

            <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600px">
                <tr align="justify">
                    <td><img alt="HEADER_IMG" class="header" src="https://mlsvc01-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/483a2626be/93869145-c989-4ae6-a9ce-6b48201903ab.jpg?ver=1493324994000">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- End Promo Code Section -->
            <!-- Promo Code Section -->


            <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#010044" width="600">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h1 align="center" style="color: white; font-family:'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;">Promo Code: CALI</h1>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- End Promo Code Section -->
            <!-- Resort Section-->


            <div class="container resort-section">
                <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="95%" style="text-align: center;">
                    <tbody>
                        <!-- Resort 1-->


                        <tr style="background-color: white; max-width: 270px; display: inline-block; margin: 7.5px;">
                            <td>
                                <a href="http://www.8664myvacation.com/rentResortInfoSheets.php?prop=tsr&promo=CALI" target="_blank"><img alt="Tahoe Seasons Resort" src=
                                "https://mlsvc01-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/483a2626be/daabeb63-91a4-4c04-9811-b5b42d74ca58.png?ver=1483132264000" style="width: 270;" title="Tahoe Seasons Resort"></a>

                                <div style="padding:10px; text-align: center; valign: top; line-height: 1.25em;">
                                    <!-- Resort name & city info --><span class="resort-name"><strong>Tahoe Seasons Resort</strong></span><br>
                                    <span class="city">S. Lake Tahoe, CA</span> <!-- End resort name & city info -->
                                     <!-- Horizontal rule -->

                                    <hr style="width: 20%; align: center; margin-bottom: 10px">
                                    <!-- End horizontal rule -->
                                    <!-- Resort strikethrough rate --><span style="color: #000000; font-size:16px"><b>From</b> <s style="color:#969696">$122/night</s><br>
                                    <br></span> <!-- End resort special rate -->
                                     <!-- Resort special rate -->
                                    <span style="color: #758b1d; font-size:20px"><b>$98/night</b></span> <!-- End resort special rate -->
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- End Resort 1 -->
                        <!-- Resort 2-->


                        <tr style="background-color: white; max-width: 270px; display: inline-block; margin: 7.5px;">
                            <td>
                                <a href="http://www.8664myvacation.com/rentResortInfoSheets.php?prop=tsr&promo=CALI" target="_blank"><img alt="Tahoe Seasons Resort" src=
                                "https://mlsvc01-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/483a2626be/daabeb63-91a4-4c04-9811-b5b42d74ca58.png?ver=1483132264000" style="width: 270;" title="Tahoe Seasons Resort"></a>

                                <div style="padding:10px; text-align: center; valign: top; line-height: 1.25em;">
                                    <!-- Resort name & city info --><span class="resort-name"><strong>Tahoe Seasons Resort</strong></span><br>
                                    <span class="city">S. Lake Tahoe, CA</span> <!-- End resort name & city info -->
                                     <!-- Horizontal rule -->

                                    <hr style="width: 20%; align: center; margin-bottom: 10px">
                                    <!-- End horizontal rule -->
                                    <!-- Resort strikethrough rate --><span style="color: #000000; font-size:16px"><b>From</b> <s style="color:#969696">$122/night</s><br>
                                    <br></span> <!-- End resort special rate -->
                                     <!-- Resort special rate -->
                                    <span style="color: #758b1d; font-size:20px"><b>$98/night</b></span> <!-- End resort special rate -->
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!-- End Resort 2 -->
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <!-- ADS SECTION-->


                <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#010044" width="600">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="width: 275px; padding: 10px"><a href="http://www.8664myvacation.com/rentHome.php" target="_blank"><img alt="VRI_Ad" height="" src=
                        "https://mlsvc01-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/483a2626be/24f8c582-4b04-4af6-9da6-2b0a182b54bf.png?ver=1486058446000" width="560"></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" colspan="2" style="width: 275px; padding: 10px;"><a href="https://www.avis.com/car-rental/profile/go.ac?D415600" target="_blank"><img alt="Avis_Ad.jpg"
                        height="" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/401702/Avis_Ad.jpg" width="560"></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!-- START FOOTER=-->


                <footer>
                    <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#63656b;display:table;" width="600">
                        <tr>
                            <td height="15" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding:20;">
                                <blockquote>
                                    <p style="color:#ffffff; font-size:10px; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; text-align:left;">Terms and Conditions:<br>
                                    PROMO CODE: CALI. Valid for new reservations booked between 5/3/2017 - 5/12/2017 for travel from 5/3/2017 - 8/31/2017. Please enter promo code CALI when making your
                                    online booking to receive best available rate. Offer is based on availability and may not be available on all room types, Rates may be higher during holiday/event periods
                                    and weekends. Cannot be combined with other offers and promotions and is subject to change without notice.</p>
                                </blockquote>
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr bgcolor="#63656B">
                            <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="padding:20px 0px;color:#000000;">
                                <table align="center" bgcolor="#63656B" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#63656B;margin-bottom:10px;" width="600px">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" style="color:#ffffff;font-weight:normal;vertical-align:top;font-size:12px;font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;line-;text-align:center;"
                                        valign="top">
                                            <div style="line-height: 2em; display: inline;">
                                                <center>
                                                    <a class="imgCaptionAnchor" href=
                                                    "http://r20.rs6.net/tn.jsp?f=001VYiWL5i82Ann9qRcISgE6Vp48wcxwnCtzt3iPLVLHE1Nb2KStjtSlaZpsSubBK-vW90CHuojdBnC8cqIWSmfwEfEosTJw_00x6b3LPt2nIOrLNT6cYshOKU511zD5sDgXwusveQqP6VGDBwGiG1Mv-fBkTEz9VTNaBX1_tVKgEQ7cQjl_S28CQ==&c=&ch="
                                                    shape="rect" target="_blank"><img alt="Vacation Resorts International" border="0" height="24" hspace="0" src=
                                                    "http://www.8664myvacation.com/eguest/images/vri-logo-footer.gif" vspace="0" width="40"></a><br>
                                                    <a href="#" shape="rect" style="color:rgb(255, 255, 255);font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none;">25510 Commercentre Dr., Suite 100<br>
                                                    Lake Forest, CA 92630<br>
                                                    866-469-8222</a><br>
                                                    &#169;2017 Vacation Resorts International
                                                </center>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- End 4 Columns -->


                    <div class="" style="height: 40px; margin:0 auto; background-color: #e4e4e4; width: 100%">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <!-- spacer -->
                </footer>
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use property with td, if you need center align text only for specific screen use media query.

td (text-align:center)

Avoid inline style, use style in css file.

Comment: style sheet must be in css. it is helpful though.